# Accessing express server from different geo location

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, server

So me and my friend are working on a MERN Stack app, I am working on backend(Node.js) and he is working on Frontend(React.js). We are from different places, My Question is how he can access my localhost server, So as to hit on my APIs.
Provide me with all the possible solutions so that my APIs are always available to him.

Comment: deploy your code on the cloud. use heroku | digital ocean | AWS free accounts. learn about git

Comment: deploy may take a few hours if you are new. but in the end, you need to use this mechanism to make your code available to the whole word.

Comment: As @mehta-rohan said you need to deploy your code on some server and give him/her the public ip of the server.

Comment: Thanks @mehta-rohan

Comment: Thanks to you too @vibhor1997a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this: https://ngrok.com/

#### Ngrok is a tool that allows you to securely open a tunnel to your local machine while ngrok is running.

Its has a free plan, or you can pay for extra features like setting a custom domain

You can install ngrok as a global npm package with:

```
npm i -g ngrok
```

And then once your server is running locally, you can start ngrok in another terminal pane/window/session and point it to the port your server is running on, below we assume the port is ‘3000’:

```
ngrok http 3000
```

This will open the tunnel, and print a url you can send to your friend to make requests against. Requests made to the url will be proxied to your localhost at the specified port. It supports HTTPS as well.

Comment: But it is not feasible if node server is off and the react person still wants to hit the api so what is the possible solution for this? The server needs to keep running

Comment: @kamal11 in that case you can use http://wiremock.org/ . WireMock is a simulator for HTTP-based APIs. It enables you to stay productive when an API you depend on doesn't exist or isn't complete.